# Position of `error_reporting()` in script

Tags: php, error-reporting

Does it matter whether I place `error_reporting()` on top or not similar to `session_start()`?

I'm asking because I want to set the error reporting level accordingly (on or off) if the deploying mode in my config is set to "development" or "production".

Comment: Any errors that occur before you call it won't be reported.

Comment: @Bramar - That depends on the default value set by `php.ini`

Comment: Not setting at the top of the first script would be pretty stupid, because well it will be pretty useless if you put it at the end.